# How does the Object.assign function work?

Tags: javascript

I would like to clone an object, on order to modify it and not affect the initial object.

```
let object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

let object2 = Object.assign(object1);
object2.c = 999;

console.log(object1.c, object2.c);
// expected output: 3 999
// real output: 999 999
```

I suppose I don't correctly use the "assign" function...

Comment: try `let object2 = Object.assign({}, object1);`

Comment: Read the documentation on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @epascarello I come from that page, is not evident...

Comment: I mean, is not evident to clone an object via `let object2 = Object.assign({}, object1);`, and as you can see, the OP is from that docs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an empty object to assign the properties with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), because of

> ```
> Object.assign(target, ...sources)
> ```

```
let object2 = Object.assign({}, object1);
```

```js
let object1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};

let object2 = Object.assign({}, object1);
object2.c = 999;

console.log(object1.c, object2.c);
```

Comment: what is the point of this "complication"? why not clone just by `Object.assign(object1);` ?

Comment: because, you treat the target as source, which does not work, to get a copy.

Comment: yes, it "works" (we obtain a copy), as we can see in the OP code, but it returns the source, not the target...

Comment: @Serge - this is a correct solution, but note that [`Object.assign`] [does a shallow clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone)-- any properties for which the value is an object will be copied by reference.  If you need a deep clone you'll need to write a recursive utility to handle it or use something like [Lodash's `cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep).

Comment: @AlexanderNied, I don't need a deep copy.

Comment: @NinaScholz, it works, I just complain about how they didn't code the default shadow clone for  `var myCloned = Object.assign(object1);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.assign({}, object1)` .
the empty object will be cloned, so `object1` will be added to the empty object.

Comment: You've got a typo -- `assigm` ==> `assign`.

Comment: what is the point of this "complication"? why not clone just by `Object.assign(object1);` ?

Comment: As I said, then you just clone the `object1`, and you want to assign `object2` to a totally new object, that's why first param is an empty object `{}`, a totally new object.

Comment: as in the OP code, should be cloned the "object1", not the "empty" object... I mean, why do not write the "assign" like if just one param, then shadow clone the given object,and it's all...

Comment: I mean, you say "the empty object wil be cloned"... why do not clone just directly the "object1"?

Comment: because then your `object2` will refer to `object1`, and if you change `object2`, `object1` will be changed too.